# Is DllGetClassObject called before or after C++ static initialization

Tags: c++, dll, com

I have a DLL that is loaded into Microsoft Management Console (MMC). It seems that its `DllGetClassObject` function is calling some initialization function of a third-party library that is known to depend on static initialization to be finished (so it must not be called before `main()` in a regular C++ program). This function seems to be failing, and the snap-in is not showing in MMC. Oddly, it loads successfully if I remove it from MMC and add it again.

Information about when exactly C++ static initialization happens in a DLL (before and after which callback) seems to be sparse, and Microsoft seems to have removed its "DLL Best Practices" paper, which is referenced in many answers and articles dealing with this kind of issues.

Is there some authoritative information anywhere (preferably on MSDN) about the order of C++ static initialization and DLL callbacks?

(I already tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject, where I would expect this to be documented)

EDIT: Moving the problematic function call from `DllGetClassObject` to `DllMain` seems to solve the problem. Still looking for authoritative documentation, though.

EDIT: Concluding from this result and the answers, the problems I had with the third-party initialization function cannot have been caused by static initialization, as static initialization is supposed to be finished before `DllMain` and thus also before `DllGetClassObject`.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain otherwise google 'dllmain raymond chen' (who can be considered authoritative)

Comment: Just use the appropriate term for this problem, google "c++ static initialization order fiasco".

Comment: @SimonMourier While I did not read all of it yet, this document mentions neither C++, nor `DllGetClassObject`. And while it does make recommendation about when to initialize static structures, I cannot implement these recommendations myself, because the timing of C++ static initialization is controlled by the compiler/linker, not me.

Comment: @HansPassant This is not about the order of initialization of multiple static variables, but about the order of the initialization of ALL static symbols in a DLL and the callbacks in DLLs defined by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without condoning or eschewing using C++ objects as globals/statics in your DLL, here is the information you're looking for. The order of operations is:

1. C/C++ global/static initialization
2. `DllMain`
3. `DllGetClassObject`

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior) describes the relationship between C/C++ global/static initialization and `DllMain`.

> ...When linked into a DLL, the VCRuntime code provides an internal DLL entry-point function called `_DllMainCRTStartup` that handles Windows OS messages to the DLL to attach to or detach from a process or thread. The `_DllMainCRTStartup` function performs essential tasks such as stack buffer security set up, C run-time library (CRT) initialization and termination, and **calls to constructors and destructors for static and global objects**. `_DllMainCRTStartup` also calls hook functions for other libraries such as WinRT, MFC, and ATL to perform their own initialization and termination. Without this initialization, the CRT and other libraries, as well as your static variables, would be left in an uninitialized state...
>
> ...On process attach, the `_DllMainCRTStartup` function sets up buffer security checks, initializes the CRT and other libraries, initializes run-time type information, **initializes and calls constructors for static and non-local data**, initializes thread-local storage, increments an internal static counter for each attach, and **then calls a user- or library-supplied `DllMain`**...

You can see all this yourself by setting a breakpoint in your `DllMain` and then looking at the stack frames that lead to `DllMain` being called. You'll find a lot of interesting things are done before your `DllMain` is even called.

As for `DllGetClassObject`: This exported function isn't called by magic. The caller of this function has to do 3 things - load your DLL (e.g., `LoadLibrary`), look up the address of the function loaded from the DLL (e.g., `GetProcAddress`), and then invoke that address using the signature known for `DllGetClassObject` implementations. You can do all that manually, but functions like `CoCreateInstance` automatically do these three things in the order described here. `DllMain` is invoked automatically when `LoadLibrary` is called, and `LoadLibrary` doesn't return until after `DllMain` returns. If `DllMain` returns a success code, the caller of `LoadLibrary` will then receive the `HMODULE` for the DLL. If `DllMain` returns an error code, the caller will never have an `HMODULE` for the DLL (`LoadLibrary` will return `NULL`), and therefore the caller cannot even find your `DllGetClassObject` function, much less call it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Don't do **anything** "interesting" in `DllGetClassObject` or `DllMain`. If you can, call your initialization code "on-demand" or at some later stage. Doing anything in the callbacks should be a last resort only (but it will most likely cause problems you might not catch during your first testing).

After reading some of the material people suggested in the comments, I concluded that

1. There is no authoritative information. As far as Microsoft is concerned, C++ and DLLs don't exist in the same universe.
2. Any non-authoritative information (such as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873/) suggests that the whole issue of C++ and DLLs is a complete mess, and that it is hard to recommend any general best practices.

In my specific situation (Native DLL loaded as MMC snap-in), it seemed to help to simply move the "problematic" code to `DllMain`. However, it turned out later that it caused problems (deadlock) at process exit.

Comment: It's generally not a good practice to answer your own questions and accept the answer, especially when the answer is as squishy as this one. For DLLs compiled with Visual C++, static initialization is guaranteed to be completed before `DllMain`, and `DllMain` must complete before `DllGetClassObject` can be called.

Comment: @MichaelGunter If you post this as an answer, preferably with a link to authoritative documentation, I will gladly mark it as the accepted answer. However, are you sure that DllMain completes before DllGetClassObject? In that case, I wonder why the initialization function I called did work in DllMain, but not in DllGetClassObject...

Comment: While my answer is not the best answer to the question, it is probably the most practical one, because the combination of C++ and DLLs has issues (see the link), and doing anything "complicated" in these callbacks should be avoided. We may discuss this separately if you disagree.

Comment: Here's the documentation you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior